# MongoDB $unwind and keep array field with each unwound document for reference

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I would like to keep the original array field with each unwound document.

Example: When unwinding the members array of a band, I would like to keep the original members array with each doc so I can reference the other members

```
{ 'name': 'the crazies', 'member': 'Tom', 'othermembers': [ 'Tom', 'Mike', 'Sally' ] }

{ 'name': 'the crazies', 'member': 'Mike', 'othermembers': [ 'Tom', 'Mike', 'Sally' ] }

{ 'name': 'the crazies', 'member': 'Sally', 'othermembers': [ 'Tom', 'Mike', 'Sally' ] }
```

Ultimately the members array should not include the name of the member already in the 'name' field but I will take what I can get if anyone has any ideas.

An approach that works was to do a $lookup on itself by the band id but seems kind of clumsy.

```
band.aggregate()
  .match( 'whatever criteria' )
  .lookup({ from: 'bands', localField: '_id', foreignField: '_id', as       'othermembers')
  .unwind({ path: 'members')
  .project({
    'name': 1
    'member': '$members.name',
    'othermembers.members.name': 1;
})
```

Thoughts???

Answer (score 0):

Before unwinding the members array, project members array as two new fields and then unwind any one of the two new fields. For example

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5c5ca7184ef14365b786e11f"),
"a" : [ 
    10, 
    20, 
    30
],
"b" : "hello"
```

}

For the above data, I am using the below query

```
db.testColl.aggregate([
{$project: {old_arr: "$a", new_arr: "$a"}},
{$unwind: {path: "$old_arr"}}
])
```

The result I get is

```
    {
    "_id" : ObjectId("5c5ca7184ef14365b786e11f"),
    "old_arr" : 10,
    "new_arr" : [ 
        10, 
        20, 
        30
    ]
}

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5c5ca7184ef14365b786e11f"),
    "old_arr" : 20,
    "new_arr" : [ 
        10, 
        20, 
        30
    ]
}

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5c5ca7184ef14365b786e11f"),
    "old_arr" : 30,
    "new_arr" : [ 
        10, 
        20, 
        30
    ]
}
```

So the old_arr field is unwinded, but for each document, you will have new_arr field with all values.